# Is there a way in C++ of saving an object and then reload it although it has a pointer as attribute?

Tags: c++, pointers, ifstream

I have an object that has this pointer 'SDL_Texture *texture' and of course some other irrelevant attributes and methods. I wanted to save the whole object to a file and then reload it in the next session.
I tried to load it and reassign the texture (that would point to a wrong memory address) before using it, but of course I get completely wrong values.
Here is the code:

```
class Entity
{
private:
    SDL_Texture *texture = NULL;
    // ...
public:
    Entity::Entity(){}
    void Entity::loadSprites()
    {
        this->texture = IMG_Load("./sprites/puppet/idle.png");
        // ...
    }
}

Entity load(const char filepath[])
{
    Entity ent;
    ifstream file(filepath);
    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&ent), sizeof(Entity));
    file.close();
    ent.loadTexture();
    return ent;
}
```

I know the idea of loading a wrong pointer is probably one of the worst things I can do but I was wondering how this can change the values of every attribute of my object, and how I can avoid this.
I also have to admit that I don't really understand how 'reinterpret_cast(&ent)' works.

Comment: Read up on serialization/de-serialization.

Comment: reinterpret_cast(&ent) takes the address of Entity ent and uses it in the read method, _as if_ it was an array of chars, i.e. char*. The file read method reads a specified (sizeof(Entity) number of chars. This is a very crude method of storing and reading objects, but could work for this simple (no inheritance) class with the following ent.loadTexture().

Answer (score 4):

The problem you are describling is about a data serialization. In such process you write all data you need into a data stream so that you can *reconstruct* the object internal state from that data later. You usually want to write the bare minimum of data required.
There are many ways to go how to implement it:

- Make `save(std::ostream & data)` member function and define constructor:
  `Entity(std::istream & data)` which constructs the object from data read from the stream.
- Use serialization library like boost::serialization (very generic, can (de)serialize *anything*)

Any case, you need to decide the data format of an object so that you can reliably read it. Just dumping the entire object to disk via fstream::write()/read() is a bad idea for many reasons:

- Objects may contain some pointers like vtable that cannot be saved. They are fixed inplace at constructor.
- If the class changes in any way after the data was dumped it would render any already saved data useless.
- Writing any data address values to file is an error: next time the program is run they are invalid. Any pointers to data need to be serialized (the data itself, not the pointer!)
- Serialization is usually a recursive process. E.g boost::serialization handles this so that you can serialize things like containers of objects. (like std::list)